# How to get a random number in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I would like to get something like the next code generated in JSTL

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${random number is even}">
        <div class="redlogo">
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <div class="greenlogo">
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This one is a bit ugly but it works...

```
<c:set var="rand"><%= java.lang.Math.round(java.lang.Math.random() * 2) %></c:set>
```

Later you can check for `${rand mod 2 == 0}` and `${rand mod 2 == 1}` to get your desired output.

Answer (score 12):

You could wrap [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) in a bean and make use of [`jsp:useBean`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/syntaxref12-149806.pdf).

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Random;

public class RandomBean {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public int getNextInt() {
        return RANDOM.nextInt();
    }
}
```

...so that you can use it in your JSP as follows:

```
<jsp:useBean id="random" class="com.example.RandomBean" scope="application" />

...

<div class="${random.nextInt % 2 == 0 ? 'redlogo' : 'greenlogo'}">
```

(note that I optimized the `c:choose` away with help of the ternary operator).

Comment: If there's always going to be just two values, I'd go for a nextBoolean ;)

Comment: just a note - if EL supports calling methods, then you can skip the bean and use `${random.nextInt() ... }` (+1 was given long ago :) )

Comment: @Bozho try you can understand. It need getter and setter

Answer (score 12):

I just want to point out, that if you are using EL 2.2 (or above), you can directly call any method in EL ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11273626/1351175)), so probably the quickest method is to initialize a bean

```
<jsp:useBean id="random" class="java.util.Random" scope="application" />
```

and then directly invoke `nextInt()` or any other method from [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) inside page:

```
${random.nextInt()}
```

or with parameter:

```
${random.nextInt(10)}
```

Comment: EL would presume that java.util.Random has a method getNextInt(). Which it hasn't.

Comment: no, it wouldn't, because you will invoke it with brackets or with arguments in brackets. Read **Invoking non-getter methods** section in [EL wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: I know some time has passed, but this is a far better solution than the selected answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hope it helps! [random taglib](http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/random.htm)

Also you may try **$Math.random** function.