# how to generate sequence of unique id in jsp starting from 1000

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i want code in jsp to generate unique id starting from 1000. Which data type can i use for it, and how to go about it. Can anyone please giude me......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`java.util.Random`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), Use `nextInt()` method and simply add `1000` to it, if you want it to be starting from `1000` , you can simply take first no as `1000`

**Also See**

- [how-to-get-a-random-number-in-jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273069/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-jstl)

Comment: java.util.Random cannot be resolved i am getting this error i have used it as follows <input type="text" name="projid" onchange="if (isNotEmpty(this))" value="<%=java.util.Random%>">

Comment: `<%@ page import="java.util.Random" %>` use this ,

Comment: Ah.. my bad.. yes you are directly using it, don't you need to create object of it . something like `value="<%=new Random().nextInt()+1000%>">`

Comment: And I still recommend ,not to use raw java in view.

Comment: thank u now i am getting it but i am getting negative values also how to avoid negative values

Comment: Use `<%=new Random().nextInt(10000)+1000%>"` this will generate a number between `0 `and `10000` and we are adding `1000` to it.

Comment: Well, Simply use `System.currentTimeInMillis()` to get the current millis which  will be unique

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate a random integer within a certain range , you can use the following snippets :

```
public int generateRandomNumber(int start, int end ){
    Random random = new Random();
    long fraction = (long) ((end - start + 1 ) * random.nextDouble());
    return ((int)(fraction + start));
}
```

For example , to get a random integer within 1000 and 8888 , you can call `generateRandomNumber(1000, 8888);`

If you want to write all the java code inside a JSP (tough I don't suggest this approach too )  , you can create a JSP page like this .You can get a random integer after every refresh.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Random"%>
<%!
    public int generateRandomNumber(int start, int end ){
        Random random = new Random();
        long fraction = (long) ((end - start + 1 ) * random.nextDouble());
        return ((int)(fraction + start));
    }
%>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>TEST RANDOM NUMBER</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>Generate Random Number:<%=generateRandomNumber(1000,8888)%></h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are welcome , you can use an Integer ArrayList to hold the generated random number .After the random number is generated ,  you first use contains() to check if ArrayList  already has such number . If yes , you generate it again . Otherwise , you put the number to the ArrayList

Comment: without using array is there a simple way to generate unique sequence id

Answer (score 2):

These answers all talk about Random numbers - the OP is asking about unique numbers. Using Random numbers, you still get the possibility of duplicates ( although that chance is admittedly small )

An easy way to get a unique number would be just to have a class that has one static synchronised method that increments a statically declared counter and returns it. Seed the counter to start at 1000.

I would implement this in a java class, rather than JSP. As Jogar points out earlier, putting raw java in a JSP can soon get out of hand.

If your application may end up running on more than one JVM ( such as in an application server cluster ) and the number needs to unique across the entire cluster, then this solution won't work. You'll need to use an external counter, such as the database based solution mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AUT_INCREMENT feature of  db. mysql db to generate unique id .

```
   create table `TableName`( 
   `v` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   PRIMARY KEY (`v`)
 )  Engine='Default' auto_increment=1000 comment='' row_format=Default
```