# Call methods in Expression Language

Tags: jsp, tomcat, el

How can I invoke a method in JSP using EL ([*Expression Language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language))?

For example:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${listStr}" begin="0" end="2" step="2">
    <p>${item.indexOf("h")}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

Here, the `item` is an object of type `java.lang.String`. This causes errors when run on Tomcat.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Answer (score 17):

This is only supported since EL 2.2. This goes in turn hand in hand with Servlet 3.0. So if you make sure that you target a Servlet 3.0 compatible container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc) with a Servlet 3.0 compatible `web.xml` declaration, then it'll just work the way you intend. If you're however targeting an older versioned servlet container, or have an older versioned or even the wrong `web.xml` root declaration, then it won't work.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

---

**Update:** Your particular problem is likely caused by a bug in Tomcat 7. It doesn't find the right overloaded method based on the given argument. Your expression works fine in Glassfish 3. All non-overloaded methods should work just fine in Tomcat.

Comment: I use Tomcat 7 , servlet 3.0 , but some method work , the other no .

ex : indexOf(104) is ok , but indexOf("h") isn't . ("h" ascii is 104) .

Comment: This is a bug in Tomcat 7 https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56147

Comment: From which version can I invoke not get methods without arguments?

Comment: @PhilipRego: Ctrl+F on "findAttribute" in your link. You'll see it's just in superclass.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it to work either(Apache Tomcat/7.0.27).

> javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert h of type class java.lang.String to int

El refuses to see the method with the correct signature. Same thing happens with indexOf("h",0). I did have success with

```
${x.contains("h")}
${x.lastIndexOf("h")}
${x.indexOf(104)}  Ascii value of 'h' is 104
```

Comment: Yes , some method is ok . the other not . :| .

Comment: Have you tried sending 'h' (a char)? char can be translated to int.