# How to access as JsonNode from session | ${user.get()}

Tags: java, json, web-services, servlets, el

I'm creating a simple session object (JsonNode)

```
JsonNode me = mapper.readValue(result, JsonNode.class);

HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("user", me);
```

The trying to access it like this.

```
${user} // works print {"id":8,"name":"jones"..}
${user.id} // trows Error "Property 'id' not found on type org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode"
${user.get(0)} // nothing printed out.
${user.size()} // return 4, id,name,username,token
```

How do would i re factor my code to fix the problem, or even the selector?

Comment: What about `${user.get('id')}`?

Comment: @mindas No it seems not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version @mindas suggested should work, unless you are using Tomcat 7. Seems that Tomcat 7 has a bug when calling overloaded methods with JSP EL ([see an issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273626/call-method-in-expression-language)). Are you using Tomcat 7?

The `${user.get(0)}` isn't printing anything because that method is for accessing the value of the specified element of an array node. Yours is not an array node and if you use `${user.get("id")}` you should get the value for the `id` field, unless you are on Tomcat 7 where you will get some error like `Cannot convert id of type class java.lang.String to int`.

You could try a quick and dirty test with `${user.findValue("id")}` and see if you at least get some result, but if you don't mind me saying, I think it will be better if you would not expose a raw object like `JsonNode` to the JSP but some sort of `User` [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) with getters and setters for `id`, `name`, `username` and `token` instead. You could then use `${user.id}` in the JSP and you will have no issue with Tomcat.

Comment: Yes i'm using Tomcat 7 and yes i get "Cannot convert id of type class java.lang.String to int" error, how do would i go go about fixing it?

Comment: Oh and btw, the json object is pretty secure, it has id,name,token, no password or anything, i dont see why use a user obj?

Comment: @Jessica: I'm not talking about security in replacing JsonNode with an user object. I'm talking about the way you access it. EL knows how to work with getters on POJOs since day one. Calling methods on objects was added in JSP 2.2 and Tomcat chockes on it for overloaded methods. JsonNode has no getters for its fields, you need to call one of the overloaded method to get fields. From here your problem! If you replace it with a POJO your problem is fixed with using ${user.id}. If you don't want to create classes just for that then maybe wrap the JsonNodes in Maps and have ${user["id"]}.