# spring jstl core check method call

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm trying to check if the return value of a method call return null in a
Spring MVC power jsp page. I'm struggling with finding the right syntax.

```
<c:if test="${result.getFieldError("name") != null}"></c:if>
```

Comment: [Note that this is only supported since EL 2.2.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273626/call-method-in-expression-language). Also, what exceptions do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quote:

```
<c:if test='${result.getFieldError("name") != null}'></c:if>
```

You can use

```
<c:if test='${not empty result.getFieldError("name")}'></c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:if test="${not empty result.fieldError['name']}"></c:if>
```